# In Powerpoint how do I add a thought bubble?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

In Powerpoint 2010 how do I add a thought bubble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Insert > Illustrations tab > Shapes` and look for **Callouts**. `Cloud Callout` is probably what you need.

[image]